# Unable to upgrade database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

below is my database code, and I am trying to upgrade it by changing the version number but
the when I run the table is not recreating or altering... anything wrong in the code plz help

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int db_version = 1;
    private static final String CL_CITY = null;
    public static final String COL_NAME = "pName";
    //private static final String TABLE_NAME = CL_CITY;
    public static String TAG = DBHelper.class.getName();
    public static String DB_PATH = "data/data/org.clock/database/";
    private static String STATUS= "STATUS";
    private static String dbName = "clock.db";
    private static final String STRING_ALTER = "ALTER TABLE "+CL_CITY+" ADD "+STATUS+" STATUS";


    protected SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
    protected Context context;
    //private Context context;
    private static SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    public DBHelper(Context context, String dbName) {
        super(context, dbName, null, 34);
        //this.dbName = dbName;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void createDb() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        Log.d(TAG, "DBChecking............ dbExist : " + dbExist);
        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error cloneing database" + e);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {

        try {
            if(checkDB == null){
                String path = DB_PATH + dbName;
                Log.d(TAG, "checkDataBase path=" + path);
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            }
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "DBChecking............ ", e);
        }
        /*if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }*/
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        Log.i(TAG, "copyDataBase database...");
        File file = new File(DB_PATH);
        Log.i(TAG, "cloneDataBase file=" + file);
        file.mkdirs();
        InputStream dbInput = context.getAssets().open(dbName);
        String outPutFile = DB_PATH + dbName;
        Log.i(TAG, "copyDataBase outPutFile=" + outPutFile);
        OutputStream dbOutPut = new FileOutputStream(outPutFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        Log.i(TAG, "copyDataBase buffer=" + buffer);
        int length;
        while ((length = dbInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            dbOutPut.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        dbOutPut.flush();
        dbOutPut.close();
        dbInput.close();
    }

    public void openDb() throws SQLException {
        String dbPath = DB_PATH + dbName;
        dataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (dataBase != null)
            dataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

if (newVersion > oldVersion){

    //db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+"staff"+" (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
          // +COL_NAME+" TEXT);");

           db.execSQL("STRING_ALTER ");

    }
    }}
```

Comment: Why dont you just call `copyDataBase()` in onUpgrade directly.

Comment: can u plz tell me what shoiuld be the code in onupgrade method

Answer (score 4):

Change `db.execSQL("STRING_ALTER ");` to `db.execSQL(STRING_ALTER);`

Also check your alter sql command. It looks pretty wrong.

Answer (score 0):

i notices you are using the wrong database path:

```
public static String DB_PATH = "data/data/org.clock/database/";
```

this should be:

```
public static String DB_PATH = "data/data/org.clock/databases/";
```

(database/ ==> databases/)

Comment: also check this blog post for a cleaner solution for using pre-loaded database with `SQLiteOpenHelper`.
http://blog.kdehairy.com/2012/08/19/using-a-preloaded-sqlite-database-with-sqliteopenhelper/

Comment: i have two database folders when i check in DDMS file explorer one with database and another database(s)....

Comment: @kdehairy- about the code in the blog what if we want to upgrade our database, we need to create a new database folder in assets?..or can we alter the table by changing the version name in onUpgrade() method a providing alter quires in onupgrade() method

Comment: sorry for being late in response. about the first question. the folder "database" is the one you have created using your code, the "databases" folder is the one created by the SQLiteOpenHelper. the later is the one you should use.

Comment: about the upgrade issue, you should do the following:
1- replace the database file in your assets folder with the new version.
2- increment the `VERSION` member in the class.